# Java sockets client application

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to figure out how java sockets work and i have this code here. Everything works if i enter value through Input stream but if I send value as String this function won't stop, it loops and won't stop.

```
public void sendToServer(String username, String shopid, String number){
String hostname = "localhost";
int port = 6789;



    Socket clientSocket = null;  
    DataOutputStream os = null;
    BufferedReader is = null;



    try {
        clientSocket = new Socket(hostname, port);
        os = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Don't know about host: " + hostname);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: " + hostname);
    }



if (clientSocket == null || os == null || is == null) {
    System.err.println( "Something is wrong. One variable is null." );
    return;
}

try {
    while ( true ) {
    System.out.print( "Enter an integer (0 to stop connection, -1 to stop server): " );
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String keyboardInput = br.readLine();
    os.writeBytes( keyboardInput + "\n" );

    int n = Integer.parseInt( keyboardInput );
    if ( n == 0 || n == -1 ) {
        break;
    }

    String responseLine = is.readLine();
    System.out.println("Server returns its square as: " + responseLine);
    }



    os.close();
    is.close();
    clientSocket.close();   
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    System.err.println("Trying to connect to unknown host: " + e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("IOException:  " + e);
}


 }
```

This is the server part that handles input:

```
 public void run() {
     String line;
try {
    boolean serverStop = false;

        while (true) {
            line = is.readLine();
    System.out.println( "Received " + line + " from Connection " + id + "." );
            int n = Integer.parseInt(line);
    if ( n == -1 ) {
        serverStop = true;
        break;
    }
    if ( n == 0 ) break;
            os.println("" + n*n ); 
        }

    System.out.println( "Connection " + id + " closed." );
        is.close();
        os.close();
        clientSocket.close();

    if ( serverStop ) server.stopServer();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "enter value"?

Comment: This is the code i have now: `System.out.print( "Enter an integer (0 to stop connection, -1 to stop server): " );
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String keyboardInput = br.readLine();` but if i asign value to `number` and call function on button click with this code inside function: `String keyboardInput = number;
  os.writeBytes( keyboardInput + "\n" );` everything works great and server actualy calculates value and returns it but it wont stop. Keeps returning value and i need to close app for it to stop

Comment: Ok ok, i havent got much sleep in a few days. The problem was with `while`...

Comment: Don't keep creating `BufferedReaders` inside the loop. Do it once. You may be losing buffered data.